# How to display a gridview maximized in a new window of the same aspx page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a fileupload control, button control and a gridview control in a single aspx page. Is it possible to display the GridView Control alone in a new maximized window on clicking the button control?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ImageViewForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.ImageViewForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var urlforpdf = document.getElementById("<%=hdnurl.Value%>");
            var data = $("#hdnurl").val();
            if (data != null & data != "" & data != undefined) {
                $("#pdfurl").css("display", "block");
                $("#pdfurl").attr("src", data);
                //alert($("#hdnurl").val());
            }
            else {
                $("#pdfurl").css("display", "none");
            }

        });

    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <style>
        .Uplaod {
            margin-left: 479px;
            height: 36px;
            width: 19%;
            background-color: dimgrey;
            color: white;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: 1px solid #333;
        }
    </style>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <br />
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <div style="text-align: center; width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <br />
            <label style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 50px;">Tennis Result</label>
            <table width="50%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                <br />
                <tr>
                    <br />
                    <td style="margin-left: 53%; width: 20%">
                        <br />
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <br />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgViewFile" runat="server" Style="height: 500px; border: 10px solid #928F8F; border-radius: 15px; margin: 0 auto" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnurl" name="name" value="" />
            <iframe style="display: none; height: 600px; width: 1000px; border: 10px solid #928F8F; border-radius: 15px;" id="pdfurl"></iframe>
            <br />
        </div>
        <br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>


**C# CODE**

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class ImageUploadForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            //{
            //    FileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath("~/TEST/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
            //   imgViewFile.ImageUrl = "~/TEST/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            //}

            imgViewFile.Style.Add("display", "none");
        }
        protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] validFileTypes = { "bmp", "gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "pdf" };
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            bool isValidFile = false;

            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < validFileTypes.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ext == "." + validFileTypes[i])
                    {
                        isValidFile = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!isValidFile)
                {
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    Label1.Text = "Invalid File. Please upload a File with extension " +
                                   string.Join(",", validFileTypes);
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    Label1.Text = "File uploaded successfully.";
                }
                string dirUrl = "TEST1" + this.Page.User.Identity.Name;
                string dirPath = Server.MapPath(dirUrl);
                // string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dirPath);
                // string dirPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirector


                if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
                }
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath);
                foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                    File.Delete(filePath);
                //var ok = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

                //.ToList();

                // save the file to the Specifyed folder  

                string fileUrl = dirUrl + "/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fileUrl));
                string exten = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                //Display the Image in the File Upload Control  

                imgViewFile.ImageUrl = fileUrl;
                imgViewFile.Style.Add("display", "block");

                if (exten == ".pdf")
                {
                    hdnurl.Value = "../" + fileUrl;
                    //pdfurl.Visible = true;
                    imgViewFile.Style.Add("display", "none");
                }
                else
                {
                    hdnurl.Value = null;
                }

                //Session["Imagename"] = FileUpload1.FileName;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use control anchoring.

Set property *Anchor* of GridView to Top, Left, Right.. it will resize with div. If your GridView is placed inside a div or container (ex Panel) then Panel/div should be anchored too.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: please follow: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx